# Python Set all dictionary values to lower case with specific key

Tags: python

I have a problem. I want to set all the values from my dictionary that are connected with the `["key1"]` to lowercase. I started to create a test dictionary:

```
# Define test devices
item1 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
}

item2 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
}

collection = []
collection.append(item1)
collection.append(item2)
```

After that, I started by tring to set every value to lowercase like this:

```
for item in collection:
    item = dict((k, v.lower()) for k,v in item.items())
```

But after that, I printed the collection, but nothing changed.
Why are all my values not lowercase and how can I set it for a specific key?

Comment: Is the variable 'dictionary' the list 'collection' to which you have appended the dictionaries item1 and item2?

Comment: Please, provide [mre] that demonstrate the problem. Your pieces of code do not match as names and container type/

Comment: Sorry, fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using for loop with dictionary, you iterate through the keys present in it. All you need to do is assign to the corresponding key using `dictionary[key] = ...`. The `dictionary[key]` in the right-hand side fetches the value associated with the key upon which you may call the `lower()` function.

This will fix the issue:

```
for key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key] = dictionary[key].lower()
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought I needed to use the item.items() thingi..... Everyone talked about that when setting the key to lower!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk If this helps, I would encourage to accept and upvote this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

help your self with this approach

```
item1 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
} 

for k, v in item1.items():
  if k == 'key1':
    item1.update({k:v.lower()})
    print(item1)
```

output

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'VALUE2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the list using the below code:

```
for item in collection:
    item.update(dict((k, v.lower()) for k,v in item.items() if k=='key1'))
print(collection)
```

**Output**

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'VALUE2'}, {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'VALUE2'}]
```

Comment: This will convert all the values to lower, But according to the condition we should focus on only `key1` which need to be lower.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   item1 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
}
for key, value in item1.items():
  item1[key]=value.lower()

print(item1)
```

> output {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in collection:
   for key in item:
    if key=="key1":
        item[key]=item[key].lower()
```

**Why?**

In python, strings are immutable. When you use `string.lower()`, you create a copy of the original string and turn all the characters into lowercases. Hence you need the key to point to the new string. Unless you reassign the new string, the old string would not be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```
# Define test devices
item1 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
}

item2 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
}

collection = (item1,item2)

for item in collection:
    for k,v in item.items():
        item[k] = v.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is just a little problem of misconception in how updating a dictionary works.
You are trying to use the item coming out of the for, while this is just a copy of the original. You could just use the key to refer to the item in the originnal dictionnary and update it:

```
# Define test devices
item1 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
}

item2 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
}

collection = []
collection.append(item1)
collection.append(item2)

for item in collection:
    for k,v in item.items():
        if k == "key1":
            item[k] = v.lower()

print(collection)
```

Comment: The condition is only for `key1`, not all the keys.

Comment: True. I was just answeringn his first question, but I added the condition so it is more complete

Answer (score 0):

Here added an extra piece of code

```
for i in collection:
    i["key1"] = i["key1"].lower()
```

Here is the file

```
item1 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
}

item2 = {
    "key1": "VALUE1",
    "key2": "VALUE2"
}
collection = []
collection.append(item1)
collection.append(item2)

print("Before operation",collection)

for i in collection:
    i["key1"] = i["key1"].lower()

print("After Operation",collection)
```

Output
[image]